# L-Kurtosis calculation

Tags: descriptive-statistics, moments, kurtosis, l-moments, shape-parameter

I am doing statistical analysis on some signal data and after some reading was thinking that L-kurtosis would be a good numerical value to use in differentiating delta trains and sine waves with similar standard deviations.

Firstly, is this likely a good assumption before I go writing some code or are there more appropriate shape summary statistics for this purpose?

Secondly, since the L-moments use factorials, I was wondering if there are some available algorithms that would efficiently calculate the L-Kurtosis value?

I would appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: cross-posted at [Computational Science](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/q/19736/20688) with a partial answer.